# Calculating sum of two columns with individual rows and result store in another column USing ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Ruby on rails platform, I have a question i.e., In my module i have table called Asset_classification in which name, type, availability, integerity, level are the fields. i want to calculate(sum) integrity & level fields  for each row and finally result should be store in another column....

Any help is appreciate

Ruby 1.9.3
Rails 3.2.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add new column `sum` in database and do this in `AssetClassification` model

```
before_save :calculate_sum

def calculate_sum
  self.sum = self.integrity + self.level
end
```

Comment: HI Ahmad Hussain, I have one more doubt while creating scaffold i will give name:string number1:string number2:string. In entering the fields name: xyz number1:low number2:high. In calculation Part low + high = integer value (is it possible  giving predefined values to low, high, medium)

Comment: If numbers are integer then why have you created them as string. If you really want to make it string then use to_i after number